# Ionic + Angular + Codeigniter4 CORS error in production

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, codeigniter-4

I have the following issue. In my local environment I can make requests without any problems from my ionic + angular app to my php backend with codeigniter 4. But when I deploy to my Hostinger server it gives me CORS errors and the support is not able to solve it. Although I think it is a server problem, here I leave you my request and the controller to see if there is any error on my part.

I have already tried modifying the .htaccess, guidelines were added by the server's technical support and nothing has solved this problem.

Comment: So you forgot to show us your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

> Hostinger server it gives me CORS errors and the support is not able to solve it.

I was able to add CORs to my Hostinger server as stated in their support docs:
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/6320787-is-cors-supported-at-hostinger

You can use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on all of our Web, WordPress and Cloud hosting plans!

Just add the following lines to your website's .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answer, if that is the correct solution, we were already applying it. In the end, we found that the problem was the url of the production environment that was incorrectly formed into just one letter and it was difficult for me to realize it.